# Can't remove tweens (tweenJS)

Tags: javascript, easeljs, tween.js

I am using [tweenJS](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/TweenJS/modules/TweenJS.html) in order to animate some images in my page.
I am creating the tweens like this:

```
star = new createjs.Bitmap(starPic.src);
stage.addChild(star);

starsLU[x] = createjs.Tween.get(star, {loop:true, paused:true})
                        .to({alpha:0.25})
                        .to({x:leftLimit, alpha:1},speedX, effect)
                        .to({y:topLimit, alpha:0},speedY, effect)
                        .wait(opt.delay);
```

However when I use

```
createjs.Tween.removeTweens(star);
```

nothing seems to happen, the image continues to move. I even add these just in case, still nothing...

```
stage.removeChild(star);
stage.update();
```

I still learn how to use tweenJS, Am I doing something terribly wrong?

Comment: if `stage.removeChild(star); stage.update()` aren't working, you're surely doing something wrong. Probably you are never calling these statements. However, we have to see the code to be sure of what is going on.

Comment: Agree with @renatopp. Output what `star` is, and it might be null. Perhaps you have a scoping issue in your functions.

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one tween you can use this

```
createjs.Tween.removeAllTweens();
```